# Displaying Image directly from database

Tags: php

apparently i have issue with displaying the image as it only show me the name of the file, is there anyway for it to display on the webpage right away?
Below is my source code along with 2screenshots of my database holding the image and the place where i want it to display at:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR); 

include("global.php");


session_start();

$receipt = $_GET['receipt'];
$userid = $_SESSION ['userid'];
if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) == false) 
{
    header ("Location: login.php");
}

$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT receipt, date, time, pick, dropoff, userid, carno, cost, branch, area, image FROM items where receipt=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $receipt);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($receipt, $date, $time, $pick, $dropoff, $userid, $carno, $cost, $branch, $area, $image);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<table border='1' style='width:40%'>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<b>Receipt ID: $receipt</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "$image";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Date of Travel: $date</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Time of Travel: $time</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Pick Up Location: $pick</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Drop Off Location: $dropoff</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Area of DropOff: $area</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Cost of Trip: $cost</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>User ID (NRIC): $userid</b>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<b>Branch of Officer: $branch</b>";
    echo "</td>";
}

echo "</table>";

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Preview:
[image: location where i want to display my image]

[image: An image file name inside the database]

Comment: use <img> tag. echo "<img src=$image>";

Comment: Write an answer @romanreign ! It'll be easier for others to see it (since this is the right answer)

Comment: @romanreign great thanks it work nicely :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<img>` tag as below

```
 echo "<img src=$image>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<img src='$image'>";
```

Learn about [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img)